# Не отображается на экране информация при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

При нажатии на кнопку хочу получить информацию об отдельной стране. Запрос отправляется успешно, результат запроса сохраняется в массив (строка 6). Но почему-то в console.log (строка 19) я получаю пустой массив и на экране информация не отображается. Ошибок в консоли нет. Если я пишу название страны в строке поиска целиком, то информация о ней отображается на экране. Что я делаю не так?

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import Filter from './Components/Filter'
import axios from 'axios'

const ShowCountries = ({countries}) => {
  const[state, setState] = useState([])

  const capital = state.find(arr => arr[0] === 'capital')
  const area = state.find(arr => arr[0] === 'area')
  const languages = state.find(arr => arr[0] === 'languages')
  const flags = state.find(arr => arr[0] === 'flags')

    if(countries.length === 0) return <p>Loading...</p>

    const countryInfo = (country) => {
      const baseUrlItem = `https://studies.cs.helsinki.fi/restcountries/api/name/${country}`
      axios.get(baseUrlItem).then(response => {
        setState(Object.entries(response.data))
        console.log(state)
      }
        )  
        if(state.length>0)
      return <div>
         <h1>{country}</h1>
         <p>{capital[0]} {capital[1]}</p>
         <p>{area[0]} {area[1]}</p>
         <p>{languages[0]} :</p>
         <ul>
           {Object.values(languages[1]).map(i => <li key={i}>{i}</li>)}
         </ul>  
         <img src={flags[1]['png']}/>
       </div>   
    }

    if(countries.length === 1) return countryInfo(countries)

    if(countries.length > 10) return 'Too many matches, specify another filter'

    if(countries.length > 1 && countries.length < 10) {
       return countries.map((country) => <div key={country}>
       <b>{country}</b>
       <button onClick={() => countryInfo(country) }>show</button><br></br>
     </div>)
    }
  }

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]) 
  const [findCountrieValue, setFindCountrieValue] = useState('')

  const baseUrl = 'https://studies.cs.helsinki.fi/restcountries/api/all'

  const findCountrie = (event) => {
    setFindCountrieValue(event.target.value)

    axios.get(baseUrl).then(response =>
      setCountries(response.data
      .map(c => c.name.common).filter(c => c.toUpperCase()
  .includes(findCountrieValue.toUpperCase()))))
  }
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Filter find={findCountrie} value={findCountrieValue}/>      
      <ShowCountries countries={countries} setCountries={setCountries}/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: includes ищет полное совпадение, а не часть строки.

Comment: С поиском проблем не было, всё что находим сохраняем в массив, состояние countries и работаем уже с ним в ShowCountries. При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, в этом вопрос.

Comment: Еще axios - асинхронный. Запрос отправляется, но вы не дожидаетесь ответа и код выполняется дальше. Т.е. вы работаете с предыдущим состоярием. Когда ответ придет, вы записываете его в состояние, но не рендерите

Comment: Поизучав ваш код, я так и не понял, зачем вы в state записываете данные от апи(видимо инфо по стране), а далее в списке выводите только первый элемент и с результатом не работаете. Рендер идет по количеству элементов в пропсе и элементы пропсов к ответу тоже не привязаны... Что делает этот код, что приходит от апишки, какой результат вы ожидаете получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем с ошибок, допущенных в коде:

метод includes ищет полное совпадение элемента проверяемым данным, в вашем случае, метод вернет true только если название страны введено полностью. Для поиска подстроки, можно использовать метод indexOf.

Компонент ShowCountries принимает список стран и отображает их названия, однако показывать детализацию будет только в том случае, если найдена только одна страна:

```
if(countries.length === 1) return countryInfo(countries)
```

Когда стран больше, то будет показан список стран, а результат работы функции countryInfo "улетит в космос", т.к. выполняется в другой функции(обработчик события нажатия кнопки) и не будет являться результатом рендера.

Постарайтесь работать с теми данными, которые к вам приходят. Вы зачем то объект превратили в массив и далее пытаетесь поиском по длинному массиву найти нужную информацию методом find.

В дальнейшем это может сказаться на производительности вашего приложения.

Компоненты в React должны опираться на свое состояние и рендерить данные исходя из него(У вас ShowCountries отрисовывает данные исходя из переданных параметров - props'ов, а изменение собственного состояния state не влияет на отображение компонента).

Когда вы работаете со списком элементов и у каждого элемента должно быть свое состояние, лучше всего выносить это в отдельный компонент.

Ниже, пример ваших компонентов, которые получают список стран и отображают детальную информацию по стране.

```js
const ShowCountry = ({ country }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const [isShow, setShow] = useState(false);
  const getInfo = () => {
    setShow((s) => !s);
    if (state.capital) return;
    const baseUrlItem = `https://studies.cs.helsinki.fi/restcountries/api/name/${country}`;
    fetch(baseUrlItem)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        res.languages = Object.values(res.languages).join(", ");
        setState(res);
        return res;
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <b>{country}</b>{" "}
      <button onClick={getInfo}>
        {isShow ? "Скрыть инфо" : "Показать подробнее"}
      </button>
      {isShow && state.capital && (
        <div>
          <h1>{state.country}</h1>
          <p>{state.capital[0]}</p>
          <p>{state.area}</p>
          <p>{state.languages}</p>

          <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", width: "fit-content" }}>
            <img src={state.flags["png"]} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [findCountrieValue, setFindCountrieValue] = useState("");

  const findCountrie = async (event) => {
    fetch("https://studies.cs.helsinki.fi/restcountries/api/all")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setCountries(
          response
            .map((c) => c.name.common)
            .filter(
              (c) =>
                c.toUpperCase().indexOf(findCountrieValue.toUpperCase()) > -1
            )
        );
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input onInput={(e) => setFindCountrieValue(e.currentTarget.value)} />
      <button onClick={findCountrie}>find</button>
      {countries.map((country) => (
        <ShowCountry key={country} country={country} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Что изменилось:

Поиск стран осуществляется по подстроке

```
c.toUpperCase().indexOf(findCountrieValue.toUpperCase())
```

Полученный список отрисовывается и каждое значение теперь живет само по себе в компоненте ShowCountry

```
{countries.map((country) => (
    <ShowCountry key={country} country={country} />
))}
```

При нажатии на кнопку, запрашивается дополнительная информация по стране. При повторном нажатии информация скрывается, если нажать еще раз, т.к. данные уже есть, то информация просто отображается и повторного запроса данных не происходит.

Тестировал в [песочнице codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/countrylist-xv3c33)

Comment: Изучаю React меньше месяца, ещё не всё понятно, поэтому так намудрила) Огромное Вам спасибо за такой подробный ответ, уже несколько дней мучаюсь. СПАСИБИЩЕ !!!